# Sorting HTML content in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

What am I doing wrong?
It is not sorting right.

JavaScript:

```
function sortDescending(a, b) {
    var date1 = $(a).data('date');
    var date2 = $(b).data('date');

    return date1 > date2;
}

$('#orderaz').on('click', function () {
    $('#jo .item').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('#jo');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agw6gvff/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback passed to the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function should return a *positive* number if the first argument is strictly greater than the second (according to your sorting needs), a *negative* number if it's smaller, and 0 if they're equivalent.

You're not doing this. You're just returning whether the first argument is greater then the second. In short, you're returning a *boolean*, which is converted then into a number where `true == 1` and `false == 0`.

In other words, *you never return a negative value* when it's needed, and this causes the issue.

Try this:

```
return date1 - date2;
```

It's a common trick for numeric sorting.